# added route to laravel project is not working

Tags: php, laravel, laragon

i am new to laravel world
i have downloaded an existing project
i have added the needed logic in a new controller and added the route for that controller to web.php
after that i tried to access the page but i was getting error 404
i thought it was something wrong with my controller so i have used the existing controller logic in my new route
i have restarted apache, mysql, laragon but still getting 404

the new route it almost like the existing one just copy past and added a character but still the old route works but not the new one

i am using laravel 9 with laragon

any advise ??

i have tried to restart laragon but it didnt work

Comment: Welcome to SO ... you are getting an error? or just a 404 message? and is this a Laravel 404 message or a webserver 404 message?  on a side, make sure your route cache is cleared:  `php artisan route:clear` ... you don't need the routes cached in local development

Comment: the error is from laravel, i am getting just the 404 error like if the the route does note exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too run:

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: only `route:clear` ... `cache:clear` clears your cache store